# Asterisk - task processor queue reached 500 scheduled tasks

Tags: asterisk, pbx

I use Asterisk 16.5.0.
Sometimes i get warning like this

```
[2020-02-19 11:31:57] WARNING[2845] taskprocessor.c: The 'stasis/m:devicestate:all-00000119' task processor queue reached 500 scheduled tasks.
```

What does it means?

**Note:** I do not use pjsip. I use classic sip peers.

Comment: Could you tell me how many SIP peers and queues this server has?

Comment: The server has about 500 sip users, but approximately 50 sip are active at the same time

Answer (score 1):

It means that the task processor queue than handles device state change notifications filled up to its high watermark of 500. This can happen if you have many devices (SIP peers and Queues).

Practically it is an indication of a (brief) overload of your Asterisk process. I am not sure if it has an effect on audio quality.

Comment: This does not affect the sound quality.